# Label styleSheet property

Tags: apache-flex, styles

In the Label class there's a property named styleSheet, but I'm getting a compilation error when trying to use it, although I'm using Flex 3 and Flash Player 9. What am I missing?

Here's my code:

```
<mx:Label xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" selectable="true">
    <mx:Script>
        override public function set data(value:Object):void
        {
             super.data=value;
             var labelStyleSheet:StyleSheet=styleSheet;
```

Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: styleSheet

Comment: Can you post the code and the error message?

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand what are you trying to do.

If you want to just set the style of the component you should use the `styleName` property.
For example to set the color red you can use:

```
<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
    .test{
        color:red;
    }

</fx:Style>
<mx:Label styleSheet="{StyleManager.getStyleDeclaration('test').getStyle()}">

</mx:Label>
```

If you are trying to loading and set an existing CSS runtime you can use the [StyleSheet](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html).
See the example in the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html) .

Anyway you are getting the compile error simply because the variable is not defined.

Davide

Comment: But the thing is, the variable is defined, but for some reason, I can't access it:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Label.html#styleSheet

Comment: Then, post the rest of the code please, I can't understand the problem with just these lines.

Comment: The compilation error is on the last line in my code. I can't continue the function because I can't use the property value...